# sorting pandas data frame based on multiple values in a single cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a data frame that contain multiple data in one column

```
    ID                                            classes
4   5792.0  Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Analysis ...
6   5915.0  Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti...
8   5931.0                        CS, Chemistry, Perspecti...
9   5991.0                                    Perspective, CS
10  5841.0  Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti...
```

the "classes" column can have values such as "Perspective, Chemistry, CS" and so on
i want to sort the above data frame based on values in the classes string

for example one output might be

```
        ID  classes                                         
4   5792.0       CS
6   5915.0       CS
8   5931.0       CS
9   5991.0       CS                            
10  5841.0       CS
```

thus sorted based on classes attended,

I searched google, but all results were sorting data frame based on single value (single value per cell)

thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "sort" do you mean you only want to see rows that contain a particular class? What is your sort criteria?

Comment: Yes, each new data frame will contain only one class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[5792.0,5915.0,5931.0,5991.0,5841.0 ],'classes':['Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti,CS, Chemistry','Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti,CS, Chemistry','Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti,CS, Chemistry','Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti,CS, Chemistry','Mechanics (any of the two sessions), Perspecti,CS, Chemistry']})
df
```

Use df.str.split to convert string in `classes` to list

```
df['classes']=df.classes.str.split(",")
```

Explode and sort by `classes`

```
df.explode('classes').sort_values(by='classes')
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: `explode`! Ha! I knew pandas had a special way to do this.

Comment: Great, i just need more time to understand it, but looks cleaner thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to sort each string in the classes column split by commas, you can try this:

```
df['string'] = df['classes'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x.split(', '))))
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i tried it out, it only removes the comma "," which is not useful

Comment: It also sorts the list. Why isn’t that working? It works for me.

Comment: He wants `N` dataframes where `N` is the number if classes. Each dataframe should only contain rows which contained their respective class from the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more "pandas" way of doing this, but here's one possible solution:

```py
cs_df = df[df['classes'].apply(lambda x: 'CS' in x)]
cs_df['classes'] = 'CS'
```

In the above example, `cs_df` should contain all of the rows from the original dataframe where `'CS'` is in `classes`.  You can do this manually or in a loop to get all your dataframes.

### Explanation:

When we use `df['classes']`, pandas returns a `numpy.Series` instance. `numpy.Series.apply` takes a function as an argument and applies it to every item in the series. For example:

```py
# square each item in the series
s1 = numpy.Series([1,2,3]).apply(lambda x: x*x)
#[1,4,9]
# root each item in the series
s2 = s1.apply(sqrt)
#[1,2,3]
```

Pandas also has special indexing logic. If you use a `Series` of `bool`s as an index on a `Dataframe`, pandas will return a `Dataframe` where the items in the index series was `True`.

So in this example

```py
s = numpy.Series([True, False, True])
df2 = df[s]
```

`df2` will only contain the rows `0` and `2` from the original `df`.

Finally, pandas also has special logic for assignment by index as well. You can set entire columns to a single scalar value without needing an explit loop:

```py
df['best_column'] = "best value"
```

In the above example, the dataframe will have a new column filled with values `"best value"`.

Comment: Hey I'm glad it works for you. However, this answer is better. You should accept it and use it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704113/4728007

Comment: I will accept the other but actually i am going with your way, since it suits my application better (after sorting i need to send each csc file to a doctor, so this is better), but really great response and greater morals

Comment: I've added a small explanation.

Comment: You really save me alot thanks, very much appreciated